Is the group of single-qubit Clifford+$T$ unitaries solvable?
Let $G_k$ be the group of unitaries generated by the $H$ and $R_Z\left(\frac{2\pi}{2^k}\right)$ gates up to a global phase (i.e $G_k$ is a subgroup of $U(2)/U(1)$). Since $G_2$ is the group of single-qubit Cliffords, we know that $G_2 \cong S_4$ is solvable ($G_2 \cong S_4 \triangleright A_4 \triangleright V \triangleright 1$), and thus $G_1 \cong C_2 \ltimes V$ and $G_0 \cong C_2$ must be as well. Is anything known about the solvability or the derived series of $G_3$, or $G_k$ in general?
My intuition is that $G_k$ is always solvable - Barrington's theorem gives a recipe to construct any logical operator as a quantum circuit without ancillae using a non-solvable group of single-qubit unitaries (see Ablayev et al), but it has been shown that the $G_k$ + CNOT gateset is not sufficient to construct general multi-controlled Toffoli gates without ancillae for any fixed $k$ (see Nie et al) - but I'm not sure how to make this precise.

TL;DR: No, if $k\geqslant 3$, then $G_k$ is not solvable. The commutator subgroup of a universal group is itself universal, so as we walk down the derived series of $G_k$ we only encounter universal subgroups. None of them is finite, let alone trivial, so $G_k$ is not solvable.

By Euler's rotation theorem, any $U\in PU(2)=U(2)/U(1)$ can be written as
\begin{align}
U=R_Z(\alpha)R_X(\beta)R_Z(\gamma).
\end{align}
But for any two non-commuting Pauli operators $P,Q\in\{X,Y,Z\}$ and any angle $\alpha$
\begin{align}
\left[P, R_Q\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\right]=P^\dagger R_Q\left(-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) P R_Q\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) = R_Q(\alpha)
\end{align}
so any $U$ can be written as a product of commutators of elements of $PU(2)$. In other words, $[PU(2),PU(2)]=PU(2)$. Thus, $PU(2)$ is a perfect group, i.e. one with a constant derived series.
Now, let $\overline{G}$ denote the closure of $G\subset PU(2)$ in the standard topology. Suppose $c\in[\overline{G},\overline{G}]$. Then
\begin{align}
c=[g^{(1)},h^{(1)}]\dots[g^{(n)},h^{(n)}]
\end{align}
for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $g^{(k)},h^{(k)}\in\overline{G}$. For any $k=1,\dots,n$, there are sequences $g^{(k)}_i,h^{(k)}_i\in G$ such that
\begin{align}
\lim_{i\to\infty}g^{(k)}_i = g^{(k)}\quad\quad\lim_{i\to\infty}h^{(k)}_i = h^{(k)}.
\end{align}
Define $c_i=[g^{(1)}_i,h^{(1)}_i]\dots[g^{(n)}_i,h^{(n)}_i]\in [G,G]$. Both product and commutator are continuous, so
\begin{align}
\lim_{i\to\infty}c_i=\lim_{i\to\infty}[g^{(1)}_i,h^{(1)}_i]\dots[g^{(n)}_i,h^{(n)}_i]=[g^{(1)},h^{(1)}]\dots[g^{(n)},h^{(n)}]=c
\end{align}
so $c\in\overline{[G,G]}$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
[\overline{G},\overline{G}]\subset\overline{[G,G]}.
\end{align}
In particular, if $\overline{G}=PU(2)$, then $\overline{[G,G]}=PU(2)$.
But if $k\geqslant 3$, then $\overline{G}_k=PU(2)$ by standard universality results. Therefore, the derived series of $G_k$ consists of groups that are all universal for $PU(2)$. In particular, the trivial group does not appear in the derived series of $G_k$, so $G_k$ is not solvable.

Very elegant argument, thanks!
